# How check value in textarea

Tags: html, automated-tests, codeception

How can I check the value in the text field. When you enter a value in this field, it is not displayed in the DOM tree. Are these the problems of this tag or the developer's jamb? Sorry for the Russian language in the English community, I hope this will not affect your answer in any way)
I have tried this method
1 $I->see("латук", ","#tone_objects_m"");
[image: Error]

[image: UI field]

[image: Element in DOM]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just grab the element and get its value

```js
let text = document.getElementById("myText").value 
console.log(text)
```

```html
<textArea  id='myText'>some text</textArea>
```